# JAR Dependency Resolution from Within /usr/share/java

Tags: java, linux

Can someone please explain how JAR files and the Java class loader make use of `/usr/share/java`? Is this a *special* directory that the JVM will perform automatic JAR loading and class lookups in, but no other?

For example, if I have `x.jar` that depends on `y.jar`. If both jars are in`/usr/share/java` the dependency, `y.jar`, is found when loading `x.jar`. But when loading `x.jar` from any other directory, I have to explicitly put `y.jar` on the classpath, even when it is still in the same directory as `x.jar`. Why is this?

Is there any way to make other directories behave like `/usr/share/java`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your distribution, `/usr/share/java` may be among the directories specified in the system property `java.ext.dirs`. The article [*Extension Mechanism Architecture*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/spec.html) explains in more detail. The location of such extensions is platform and version dependent, as mentioned in [*Installed Extensions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html).

Addendum: You can examine the property on your platform with the following line of code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs"));
```

Addendum: Looking closer, `/usr/share/java` does not appear in any system property; the effect may be due to the `Class-Path` property of the relevant JARs' manifest. Using this convenient [utility](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/manifesto), it's possible to examine them.

```
/usr/share/java/ant-bootstrap.jar 
Class-Path: ant.jar xml-apis.jar xercesImpl.jar xalan.jar

/usr/share/java/openoffice/java_uno.jar 
Class-Path: jurt.jar ridl.jar ../../lib/ ../bin/

/usr/share/java/openoffice/juh.jar 
Class-Path: ridl.jar jurt.jar ../../lib/ ../bin/

/usr/share/java/openoffice/jurt.jar 
Class-Path: ridl.jar unoloader.jar ../../lib/ ../bin/
```

Comment: Best answer. Can you confirm that only jars in the relative path, must be in an 'extension' directory to load. This would explain why they don't load when in the same relative path, but outside of the 'extesion' dir.

Comment: I tested 'java.ext.dirs' output: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext -- Unfortunately, I don't see how this links to /usr/share/java on my system. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It's all about your [classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

There is nothing special about `/usr/share/java` other than it is where Debian installs jars that are downloaded form its package manager. I assume they are added to the classpath whenever they are needed by a java program installed by the package manager.